# Generating Ids of inputs dynamically

Tags: javascript, uniqueidentifier, dynamically-generated

Am working on an application which has some input fields on a row, On the side **there is an addition icon whereby when the user clicks an additional row is added dynamically containing the input fields**. I want to generate the ids of the proceeding inputs field dynamically when the user clicks on the add button icon.

Kindly assist?

**Markup code**

```
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="1" size="4" id="inp1" value="">
        <input type="text" name="2" size="4" id="inp2"  value="">
        <input type="text" name="3" size="4" id="inp3"  value="">
        <input type="text" name="4" size="4" id="inp4"  value="">
        <input type="text" name="5" size="4" id="inp5"  value="">  +   
    </div>
//Icon to add another row of input fields dynamically
<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need an id? And why would you only need to generate the id and not the name?

Comment: @Andreas I need a unique id for each input field on each row to be unique,, am using it in another functionality..

Comment: There's almost no good reason for such ids, hence my question. Could you add some example which shows how you're using them?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the button to add another DIV containing five inputs each time?

Comment: @Headbank  Yah exactly with a unique id on each input on all rows ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to know the next index/number of the element you want to add, to ensure that it is unique and follows the numbering you have already in place for your pre-existing elements.

As you want to add inputs in groups of 5 (and grouped in a new `<div>`), I would suggest that you add an outer wrapping element so that we can inject new `<div>` (and the inner 5 new `<input>` elements) correctly.

For each time the button is clicked, you will want to create a new container `<div>`, and then use a simple `for` loop to iteratively add 5 new `<input>` elements. In each iteration you increment the unique ID:

```js
// Starting number of inputs
let count = 5;

// Wrapper
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', () => {

  const container = document.createElement('div');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Increment the count to ensure that it is unique
    count++;

    // Create your new `<input>` element
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'text';
    input.name = count;
    input.size = '4';
    input.id = `inp${count}`;

    container.appendChild(input);
    
    // Optional: add empty whitespace after each child
    container.append(document.createTextNode(' '));
  }
  
  wrapper.appendChild(container);
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div>
  <input type="text" name="1" size="4" id="inp1" value="">
  <input type="text" name="2" size="4" id="inp2" value="">
  <input type="text" name="3" size="4" id="inp3" value="">
  <input type="text" name="4" size="4" id="inp4" value="">
  <input type="text" name="5" size="4" id="inp5" value="">
</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btn">Add new input group</button>
```

Comment: Thanks alot,, Is it possible whereby when I click on the button it adds another DIV containing five inputs each time with each input containing a unique id..

Comment: @Martin When you mean unique, you mean you want to increment the number after the `inp` string? E.g. `inp6` to `inp10` the first time you add 5 new rows... and then the next addition will add 5 new inputs of ID `inp11` to `inp15`?

Comment: @Martin Got it. See updated answer for proof-of-concept.

Comment: ,, Thanks alot it works well.. Kindly look at the code on this link https://jsfiddle.net/facgwbsm/   I have used your code to add rows dynamically which works well,, In addition to that am trying to add more rows and when the user selects any number from the table it is populated in the rows and when he hovers over them the background color changes on the whole row and on the table.. Kindly assist on that..

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let input = document.createElement('input');
 input.id = 'input' + i;
  document.querySelector('div').appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply done:

```js
var inputContainer = document.getElementById("inputContainer"),
  cnt = 1;

function generateInput() {
  cnt++;
  inputContainer.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="' + cnt + '" size="4" id="inp' + cnt + '" value="">';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="inputContainer">
  <input type="text" name="1" size="4" id="inp1" value="">
</div>

<i class="fas fa-plus" onclick="generateInput()"></i>
```

In my example, I am just incrementing the `cnt` var every time the `generateInput()` function is called - then appending the input to the `inputContainer` with its new unique `name` AND `id`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

How about this? (I have put the Add button outside the DIV containing the inputs, but it can go inside if you prefer.)

```
<div class="inputSet">
    <input type="text" name="1" size="4" id="inp1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="2" size="4" id="inp2"  value="">
    <input type="text" name="3" size="4" id="inp3"  value="">
    <input type="text" name="4" size="4" id="inp4"  value="">
    <input type="text" name="5" size="4" id="inp5"  value="">
</div>
<button onclick="addInputSet(this);">ADD</button>
<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
```

Javascript:

```
var rowCount = 5;
function addInputSet(btn) {
    var row = document.querySelector('div.inputSet').cloneNode(true);
    var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i of inputs) {
        i.name = (++rowCount).toString();
        i.id = 'inp' + rowCount;
    }
    btn.parentNode.insertBefore(row,btn);
}
```